# Undefined reference to "main" in minimal C program

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to understand C compilation in a little more depth, and so I'm compiling and linking "manually". Here is my code

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

And here is what I'm putting into my console (Windows):

```
gcc -S main.c
as main.s -o main.o
ld main.o
```

And when trying to link, I get:

```
main.o:main.c:(text+0x7): undefined reference to `__main'
```

Comment: Run `gcc -v main.c` to see what commands the compiler actually runs.  Note that it runs a vastly more complex command line for `ld` than the one you give.

Comment: GCC's extremly long `ld` arguments are not always mandatory. A simple `Hello, world` program can be perfectly linked only with : `ld -lc -lkernel32 src.o -o src.exe`.

Comment: @RyanB I get "cannot find -lc".

Comment: @RyanB, i'm afraid that depends strongly on the architecture.  Main is a normal function (does not have anything special) so for it to be called, you must provide to the linker a piece of code that does the actual parameter gathering from command line, prepare the `argc` and `argv` parameters, stores properly the environment and then makes a call to `main()` getting the result code (in case `main()` does a `return exit_value;`) and do the proper `_exit(2)` call (after calling all the `atexit(3)` registered calls). This is done normally by modules as `rt.o`, `crt.o`, etc. and is arch dep.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You didn't link any of the necessary support libraries. C global objects like stdin, stdout, stderr don't just appear from nowhere. Command arguments and environment variables are pulled from the operating system. And on exit all those `atexit()` functions get called and the return code from `main` is passed to `exit(return_code)`. Etc.

Check out the commands `gcc -dumpspecs`, `gcc -print-libgcc-file-name`. Look at all of the other libraries in that directory. You'll find a lot of those libraries and object files referenced in the output of dumpspecs. I don't know exactly when or how those spec rules are interpreted but you can probably get the idea. And I think the GCC info pages `info gcc` explain it in detail if you dig in far enough.

`info gcc` and then press 'g' and then enter 'Spec Files'

And as Jonathan Leffler said, the shortcut is to run gcc with the verbose option: `gcc -v` and just see what commands it used.

Comment: But if the problem is support libraries, why is the undefined reference to "__main"?

Comment: @JackM That is the function that does the actual work in `main`, see e.g.: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html

Comment: Also, if you want to dig into ASM, a good practice will be to turn optimizations off (-O0 flag). Here it's useless since there are any functions and any optimizations to be made, but I think it's worth pointing out.

Comment: @JackM, `__main` is the actual program entry point.  It is not the same identifier as `_main`, which is the internal normal name for the `main()` function.