# gcc ld linker issues [Need Help]

Tags: c, gcc, command

I had a simple programs which only provide simple hello world program.
And I have convert it to Hello.o file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    printf("This is a hello world programs.");

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I use

> ld Hello.o -o Hello.exe

It provide this error

> ld: Hello.o:Hello.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to __main
>   ld: Hello.o:Hello.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to printf

But I can link the object with the gcc command, may I know why???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to "main" in minimal C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134415/undefined-reference-to-main-in-minimal-c-program) - note the first comment that says `gcc -v Hello.c` will show you the `ld` command it uses.

Comment: When you call the linker explicitly, rather than letting the C compiler do it, it doesn't automatically add the standard C libraries.